# What is the difference between `path` and `fullPath` in VueJS router?

Tags: javascript, vuejs2, vue-router

In my `router.js` file, when I'm using the `beforeEach` method, I get `path` and `fullPath` in the properties of `to` and `from` parameters. I'm wondering which one I should use for redirection purpose. I've seen both been used and I don't when to use which, and what is the difference between both.

An exemple:

```
export default new Router({
    mode: 'history',
    base: process.env.BASE_URL,
    routes: [{
        path: 'login'
        beforeEnter: (to, from, next) => {
            console.log(to, from) // the routes
            if (User.loggedIn()) {
                next(from.fullPath) // or maybe `from.path`
            } else {
                next()
            }
        },
    }]
})
```

Comment: $route.fullPath :The full resolved URL including query and hash.  $route.path:A string that equals the path of the current route, always resolved as an absolute path. e.g. "/foo/bar".

Answer (score 16, accepted):

From the [Vue API Reference](https://router.vuejs.org/api/#the-route-object):

> - **$route.fullPath**
>
>   - type: `string`
>       The full resolved URL including query and hash.
> - **$route.path**
>
>   - type: `string`
>       A string that equals the path of the current route, always resolved as an absolute path. e.g. "/foo/bar".

Answer (score 1):

path: A string that is equal to the path of the current route,
always resolved as an absolute path.
Example: /user/11/posts, /user/37/posts

fullPath: The complete URL, including query and hash.

Others...

params: An object that contains key / value pairs of
segments.
query: An object that contains key / value pairs of the
url value string. For example, for
/ foo? user = 1, we have $ route.query.user == 1.
hash: The hash of the current path (without #), if one exists. If
no hash is present, value will be a string
empty.
matched: An Array containing route records for all
nested path segments of the current route. The
route records are the copies of the objects in the
route configuration.
name: The name of the current route, if one exists.